# Do placed units increase in damage when you level up the ability?

Tags: league-of-legends

For spells like Heimerdinger's turret and Shaco's boxes, say I place the unit then level up the ability. Do the existing placed units increase in damage, or does the ability level up only apply to units placed after leveling up?

This question is asking for all placeables, not just traps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The abilities will level up with you.

After placing a [Teemo](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Teemo) Mushroom, [Shaco](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shaco) box, [Caitlyn](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Caitlyn) trap, [Nidalee](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nidalee) trap, or any other placeable unit, when you level up the respective skill, the placed unit will level up as well and receive an increase in attributes such as damage.

Note: [Heimy](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Heimerdinger)'s placed turret's health will not increase if you level up the skill

Also, the placed units are basically referencing your skill in its current state, so buying items will have an affect on already placed units, same as levelling them would.

Comment: Will it deal more damages if you buy items ? For example, I put a shroom and I have 0 AP. if I back and buy a tome, will my mushroom deal more damage?

Comment: @Fabinout Good question! The answer is yes, because the placed units are basically referencing your skill in its current state, buying items will have an effect on placed units, same as levelling them would. I will add this to my answer

Comment: However, if I'm correct, I believe that Heilmer's turrets do NOT receive the HP upgrade. So if you place a turret that has maximum 200 hp, the next level you can place turrets at 250 hp, the turret that is still up will have 200 hp, and not 250.

Comment: Could i ask if you have a slow moving projectile attack (like nidalee her spear) and you level your skill WHILE the spear has been thrown (Throw spear -> level ability -> spear hits). Do you then get the damage / status upgrades?

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire good catch! Just tested it and heimy's turrets do not actually increase in health. Editing my answer now

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Any projectile attacks do not level up as their stats are set when they are first thrown (: