# Do placed items deal more damage per tick after the initial tick if an item is purchased?

Tags: league-of-legends

As a follow up to [Do placed units increase in damage when you level up the ability?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142218/do-placed-units-increase-in-damage-when-you-level-up-the-ability), what if I put a shroom, someone steps on it, takes one tick damage, before second tick I buy a deathcap. Does the second tick deal more damage?

Comment: what do you mean by tick?

Comment: the game doesn't continuously deal periodic damage like teemo shrooms but instead deals damage in small bursts called ticks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place a Teemo shroom and then buy Deathcap then your shroom will increase in damage automatically.

Ex:

- Placed shroom will do 150 dmg
- You buy Deathcap
- Placed shroom will now do 250 dmg

Once the shroom explodes it will not change in damage.

Ex:

- Placed shroom will do 150 dmg
- Vayne steps on the shroom and it explodes
- You buy Deathcap, Zhonyas, Void Staff, and Liandrys all at once
- The DoT damage will not spike to 500 dmg instantly. The shroom will still do 150 dmg.

Comment: This is super interesting. Do you have a source for it? Where did you find this information?

Comment: @GarrettJ League of Legends is known to calculate damage at the time of application. You can easily test this in a custom game.